# Nodejs crypto.getHashes() returns an empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, exceljs

I was using [exceljs' sheet protection](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs#sheet-protection) feature when I encountered an error–`Error: Hash algorithm 'sha512' not supported!`. After taking a look into it's source files I discovered the cause of the error: `crypto.getHashes()` is returning an empty array. I can't seem to find a solution nor the reason for the empty array, any ideas?

Node v11.2.0

[ExcelJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/exceljs) v3.6.0

#### src/routes/export-excel/customer.ts

```js
import ExcelJS from "exceljs";

const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();

// workbook config

workbook.eachSheet(async (worksheet, sheetId) => {
  worksheet.eachRow((row, rowNumber) => {
    row.eachCell((cell, colNumber) => {
      switch (exportCols.getCodes()[colNumber - 1]) {
         // other case statements
         case "date_created":
         case "date_modified":
           cell.protection = { locked: false }; // locks the cells under the date created & modified columns
           break;
      }
    })
    await worksheet.protect("passWord123", {
        selectLockedCells: false,
        formatCells: true,
        insertRows: true,
        // other config props 
      });
  })
})
```

#### exceljs lib - *defenition of the protect method*

`node_modules/exceljs/lib/utils/worksheet.js Worksheet.protect`

```js
// Worksheet Protection
  protect(password, options) {
    // TODO: make this function truly async
    // perhaps marshal to worker thread or something
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.sheetProtection = {
        sheet: true,
      };
      if (password) {
        this.sheetProtection.algorithmName = 'SHA-512';
        this.sheetProtection.saltValue = Encryptor.randomBytes(16).toString('base64');
        this.sheetProtection.spinCount = 100000;
        this.sheetProtection.hashValue = Encryptor.convertPasswordToHash(password, 'SHA512', this.sheetProtection.saltValue, this.sheetProtection.spinCount);
      }
      if (options) {
        this.sheetProtection = Object.assign(this.sheetProtection, options);
      }
      resolve();
    });
  }
```

#### exceljs lib - *defenition of the convertPasswordToHash method*

`node_modules/exceljs/lib/utils/encryptor.js Encryptor.convertPasswordToHash`

```js
convertPasswordToHash(password, hashAlgorithm, saltValue, spinCount) {
    hashAlgorithm = hashAlgorithm.toLowerCase();
    const hashes = crypto.getHashes();
    console.log("supported hashes", hashes) // <== hashes was empty w/c caused the 'Hash algorithm '${hashAlgorithm}' not supported!' error to be thrown
    if (hashes.indexOf(hashAlgorithm) < 0) {
      throw new Error(`Hash algorithm '${hashAlgorithm}' not supported!`);
    }

    // Password must be in unicode buffer
    const passwordBuffer = Buffer.from(password, 'utf16le');
    // Generate the initial hash
    let key = this.hash(
      hashAlgorithm,
      Buffer.from(saltValue, 'base64'),
      passwordBuffer
    );
    // Now regenerate until spin count
    for (let i = 0; i < spinCount; i++) {
      const iterator = Buffer.alloc(4);
      // this is the 'special' element of Excel password hashing
      // that stops us from using crypto.pbkdf2()
      iterator.writeUInt32LE(i, 0);
      key = this.hash(hashAlgorithm, key, iterator);
    }
    return key.toString('base64');
  }
```

If anyone needs more clarification please don't hesitate to leave a comment down below.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide more inforamtion such as code that you have wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [bug on an unrelated project](https://github.com/montagejs/collections/issues/162) that suggests `crypto.getHashes` can return an empty array if the array prototype has been modified. In the bug report, it was due to the use of [collections.js](https://www.collectionsjs.com/map).

Modifying the array prototype, either by your own code or by a third-party module imported before the `crypto` module, can cause `crypto.getHashes` to return an empty array.